# Multiple tables having the same column header order using datatables.net

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have multiple tables that are initialized using the same configuration (`colReorder` is enabled). What I like to do is enable syncing column headers when the user reorders columns on one table.

What I did is listen to `column-reorder` on the tables and then reorder programmatically the columns on the other tables. The problem comes up when the same function gets called after the programmatic reordering.

What's the best solution for this problem?

Comment: It's great to describe the problem - but you can also demonstrate the problem to us with a [mre] - for example, by using a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/12567365), with some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the event handler responds synchronously...

I'd have a 'global' `isBeingHandled` flag, initialised to false.

In the common event handler, **if the flag is true then abort handling the event**. Otherwise set it to true and continue calling the API for the other tables.

Finally, once the initial handler has finished notifying the other tables set the flag back to false.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's really so obvious when I think about it.